# How to keep the comment /*webpackIgnore:true*/ in bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, dynamic, bundle

I created a JS lib with some dynamic import init, so I placed `/*webpackIgnore:true*/` inside the import command as described by Webpack not to resolve the path variable passed into `import` function.

Now is my app, it uses the lib said above.

When bundling the app, the comment webpackIgnore is no longer inside the lib bundle, and thus Webpack shows warning:

```
WARNING in ./src/libs/my-lib/dist/lib.bundle.js 1:173737-173746
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

In the lib bundle those dynamic imports are still `import(...`, but in the app bundle when Webpack minifies again, those dynamic imports are `x(...` where x is some minified letter.

I'm guessing of some solutions but don't know how to make it

- Tell webpack to keep the webpackIgnore comment in the lib bundle
- Tell webpack not to show warning when bundling the app (this is dangerous, because possibly webpack is resolving the variable passed to `import(...)` as null? but practically checked that Webpack leaves those dynamic imports as-is)

Comment: Webpack feature request: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/18136